# How to save web application input data in the same web location?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to save input data from web application in the same web location where the .html file placed. The saved file should be over ride with the new data every time we click the button. Currently, code downloads file to local. How to place the file in the web location and it should be over ride with new data?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        input[type=text], textarea, select {
            font: 17px Calibri;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        input[type=button]{ 
            font: 17px Calibri;
            width: auto;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 7px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>        
        <!--Add few elements to the form-->

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
        </div>        
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="bt" value="Save data to file" onclick="saveFile()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let saveFile = () => {      
        // Get the data from each element on the form.
        const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
           
        // This variable stores all the data.
        let data = 
            '\r Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n '         
    
        // Convert the text to BLOB.
        const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
        const sFileName = 'formData.txt';      // The file to save the data.

        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        newLink.download = sFileName;

        if (window.webkitURL != null) {
            newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        }
        else {
            newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
            newLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(newLink);
        }
        newLink.click(); 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't allow save or read files locally without user's consent (aka download/upload). If you need store data for your website/application, you can use [`WebStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) instead.